# Trace.axd returns YSOD not custom error

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, stack-trace, ysod

This is officially driving me crazy...... I have a website on IIS7 running ASP.Net 3.5. Tracing is off and I have custom errors configured, however when I access www.mysite.com/trace.axd I receive a standard ASP.Net YSOD instead of my custom error page. The status returned is 500, however some more weird as using Cassini or Dev Server the status is 403.

So my question is how do I return my custom error page on the live box instead of the standard ASP.Net YSOD?

Custom Errors Config:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/Error.aspx" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
<error statusCode="404" path="~/404.aspx" redirect="~/404.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" /></customErrors>
```

Trace Settings:

```
<tracing>
            <traceFailedRequests>
                <add path="*.aspx">
                    <traceAreas>
                        <add provider="ASP" verbosity="Verbose" />
                        <add provider="ASPNET" areas="Infrastructure,Module,Page,AppServices" verbosity="Verbose" />
                        <add provider="ISAPI Extension" verbosity="Verbose" />
                        <add provider="WWW Server" areas="Authentication,Security,Filter,StaticFile,CGI,Compression,Cache,RequestNotifications,Module" verbosity="Verbose" />
                    </traceAreas>
                    <failureDefinitions timeTaken="00:00:00" statusCodes="500" />
                </add>
            </traceFailedRequests>
        </tracing>
```

Any help here is much appreciated, let me know if you need anything else :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get a custom error page for trace.axd in MVC3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724771/how-can-i-get-a-custom-error-page-for-trace-axd-in-mvc3)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the tracing HTTP handler in the Web.config file:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- remove TraceHandler-Integrated - Remove the tracing handlers so that navigating to /trace.axd gives us a 
         404 Not Found instead of 500 Internal Server Error. -->
    <handlers>
      <remove name="TraceHandler-Integrated" />
      <remove name="TraceHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Navigating to /trace.axd now gives us a 404 Not Found instead of 500 Internal Server Error.